# Flutter two widgets in body?

Tags: flutter, dart

So my flutter app works fine, however I want to make some changes to it.

The 1st change I want to do is create a horizontal scroll widget that has images that are clickable that change stations.

But to do this I first need to join two widgets into one.

In my home_widget.dart file I have this code:

```
final List<Widget> _children = [TracksWidget(),
        NewsWidget(),
        AboutWidget()];
```

The code above changes the body section of the home_widget.dart section. But now what I want to do is add StationsWidget() to the bottom of the TrackWidget() - Note this widget refreshes every 30 seconds. So ideally I need to make sure it does not refresh with it.

So can a body have two widgets?

Full code of test.dart (which is where I am trying to add the widget)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'trackswidget.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // final Color color;

//  PlaceholderWidget(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    double c_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return new Container (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
      width: c_width,
      child: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column (
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Child: TracksWidget()
            ],

        ),


            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Advertise on ',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children:
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The error I am getting is

> 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
> Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'List'.
> children: TracksWidget,

Just so you all know what I am trying to achieve. We redesigned our iOS Swift app and now want our flutter app to match.

[image: Swift App.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, **no**, the `body` takes exactly *one* `Widget`. You could say it takes  *none* if you pass `null`, but you cannot pass more than one.

However, there are widgets that group other widgets. Your one body widget could as well be a `Row` and that row can have multiple child widgets.

You already did that in your title.

A nice graphical representation can be found [in the documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout).

Comment: But I could add it if a make two rows? Sorry still learning - also updated my question with a screenshot of what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: still reading (not really a good reader) I am more of a visual learner.

Comment: I have tried to create a TestWidget that has a column that then request the TrackWidget() but no success.

Comment: I have updated the question with my sample from TestWidget.dart and the error code @nvoigt

Comment: Just remove the "Child:":  `Column( children: [ TracksWidget() ] ),`